# Chartboost interstitial : "not in the window hierarchy!" warning

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, chartboost

On iOS, when I displayed a Chartboost interstitial, I have "sometimes" (yes.. not all the time) the following message when I clicked on the interstitial :

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I just call Chartboost like that:

```
[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationGameOver];
```

And at startup I cached this interstitial:

```
[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] cacheInterstitial:CBLocationGameOver];
```

I really don't understand this issue. And it's not all the time. I can't explain and understand why sometimes it works (When I touch the interstitial I have the App Store opened) and why sometimes the interstitial just disappeared and nothing happens.

I tried since 3 or 4 months to ask Chartboost about this but I never had a good answer.

Comment: The problem is solved with the last SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the view where Chartboost should show the ad. For doing that there is a method call:

```
[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] setRootView:YOUR_VIEW];
```

With that sentence you can make Chartboost show ads in an specific view.

You should call this one just before calling "showInterstitial"

UPDATE:

With the version 5.0 of the SDK they have changed this method. Now you should use

```
[Chartboost showInterstitial:{view Controller} location:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

But with some versions this method doesn't appear in the Chartboost.h file. If this is your case, simply add this line on this file:

```
+ (void)showInterstitial:(UIViewController *)viewController
            location:(CBLocation)location;
```